# Getting Dialing country code from google places api

Tags: google-places-api

i am using google places api in my project. i would like to know is there any possible way to get dialing code such  as (+91) for given a place id from google places api.

Reference taken

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it from the `international_phone_number` attribute in the result object. https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Comment: this international_phone_number attribute will be there for every place means whether it will be available for every places